# How to disable/block a device from asking "Take photo" option during file uploads

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multiple-file-upload

I have a serious issue on multiple file uploads. I have a form that has multiple file upload field. It normally works well in the desktop devices. but when it comes to mobile devices, it asks the user to access camera to take photos.

The problem is whenever uses try using a camera to take photo and upload, it only allows one single file(image) for the user to upload. if the user tries capturing multiple images, only the first image data getting passed through the form.

I use AJAX/PHP to upload the file and jQuery to validate it.

Is there any possible way that I can disable/block users from accessing camera to take a picture. Or if it's not possible, how can I pass all the captured image data through the form.

Comment: Sounds like `multiple` is enabled already.  What's wrong with having multiple photos taken?  They should all go through.  If they aren't, it might be a bug with a particular device.

Comment: it is enabled already. the problem is camera won't allow user to take multiple pictures. if he takes also only the recent image getting passed through the form. :(

Comment: Have you tried other devices?  Sounds like a bug in the camera app, not yours.

Comment: @Brad I've tried with android devices too. It asks the user to take photos. but not allowing the users to take multiple pictures..